# Using .NET Authentication for whole site and internal sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, membership

I have a site that has certain areas that are password protected with .NET membership.  I need to make a staging site that encapsulates the whole site in another password protected area controlled by admins.

Can I use 2 membership databases in one application?

Is there a better way to do this?

I am using web forms still and forms authentication.

Comment: Why not make a link to the standalone staging application and forget about any problem? You'd then only need to protect that link and the app as usual

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Create two applications in IIS: production and staging. Create a database for each of them. Instead of encapsulating the site, just make a link to it.

Comment: The linked site needs to be locked down by the first login? Is there a good way to protect that in IIS and only allow users to enter it if they logged in? btw thanks for your help :)

Comment: The second site would have its own login, unless you are willing to implement some kind of SSO. Otherwise, if your users don't mind having to login twice, just put Membership on both of the sites and put only trusted people in the second one

Comment: How do I protect the second site and put only trusted users there. the second site is has some none password protected parts too

Comment: Read about Multitenancy software architecture